# How to throttle resilience4j rate above memory threshold?

Tags: java, resilience4j

I currently have an application that just throws everything it got a resilience4j as tasks comes in. However, from time to time, the JVM crashes with an OutOfMemoryException. The tasks vary greatly from a few bytes to hundreds of megabytes per task which makes it very hard to limit the rate based on the task count as we need the maximum throughput possible.

How can I configure resilience4j to reduce the rate when a certain memory usage threshold is reached?

Answer (score 1):

Right now, Resilience4j provides no option to automatically reduce the size of a Bulkhead or change the rate limit of a RateLimiter based on memory consumption.
You have to implement your own Filter which rejects incoming request/messages, if the memory consumption is too high.
Do you stream the incoming payload? How do you know upfront if the payload size of the task is too big?

Comment: Seems like I will need to redesign the solution. I was hoping for a quick-fix.